# Can I make javascript run a function when it encounters an undefined element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm maintaining a really old Web Forms application that is glued together with IE6 compatible javascript.  This means that elements can be accessed in JS without needing to be initialised first.

What I mean is that using this is 'valid':

```
txtIngredient.value = 'potato';
```

In order to get this to work in newer browsers, like Chrome, Firefox, etc, this code becomes:

```
document.getElementById('txtIngredient').value = 'potato';
```

Obviously, Chrome, Firefox, etc, throw out an undefined error when encountering the former statement, and the JS stops executing due to the exception raised.

At the moment I'm running through the code and porting it over to make it look more like the latter, but I was wondering, could I write an error handler to handle undefined errors, which would catch when these situations occur, and then somehow return that element if it found it in the DOM and re-attempt the statement?  If so this would save a lot of work.

EDIT: For example:

This code won't work:

```
function ShrinkDetails() {
        document.Form1.btnExpand.value = "+ Dispense Details";
        trDateDispensed.style.display = "none";
        trDuration.style.display = "none";
        trStartDate.style.display = "none";
        trRepeats.style.display = "none";
        trQuantity.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Chrome etc throws an undefined error on document.Form1.

This code would work though:

```
function ShrinkDetails() {
        document.getElementById('btnExpand').value = "+ Dispense Details";
        document.getElementById('trDateDispensed').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('trDuration').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('trStartDate').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('trRepeats').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('trQuantity').style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Not obvious why it would throw error if that ID exists at the time the code runs. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: It depends on the code. You can just check if it is equals to undefined and if it is try and look for the element in the dom and return it. But it would take about the same amount of time inserting the code as it would to rewrite it. I guess you can do some fancy try catch block but I would have to see more of the code to be able to help

Comment: @charlietfl "Not obvious why it would throw error if that ID exists at the time the code runs" - really? I thought that to access an element in the DOM you needed to initialise it through document.getElementById.  Apparently in IE6 you could just pluck things out of the DOM without using that, but this was propriety and isn't a thing anymore (which is really good).

Comment: The real issue is why wouldn't the elements exist? If they are inserted after page load you would need to make sure you don't query for them until they do exist. Also since you tagged this with `jQuery` ... using that would solve all potential for errors

Comment: @charlieftl I think we misunderstand each other :) The elements do exist in the DOM but in IE6 you can just call them by their ID, and it's the same(ish) as just using getElementById.  The elements exist in the DOM, but they have not been referenced correctly in JS.  Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to do a try/catch for the reference error that you would get?

```
try {
   var myVar = txtIngredient;
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
  // code here
}
```

Comment: While this would likely work, from looking at the edit to my question, wrapping every statement in a try catch block would be massive... I want to essentially have the propriety code fail, and then in the error handler, find the element using getElementById and retry whatever failed.

Comment: Horrible idea: try tampering with ReferenceError :)